# Apache: Disable *parsing* of htaccess in webdav

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, webdav

I have following directory layout:

```
/var/www/
    example.com/
        logs/
        html/
        stuff/
```

Apache is configured to normally serve from `/var/www/example.com/html`

I have configured webdav to work for the url `https://example.com/server-admin` and allow access to the other dirs, too:

```
<VirtualHost>
...
    Alias /server-admin /var/www/example.com/  
    <Location /server-admin >  

        Dav on

        AllowOverride None
        ...
```

With `AllowOverride None` I want to disable htaccess files so they don't break webdav operation.

This kind of works. *But*: if I upload an syntactically broken htaccess file everything falls apart with an 500 internal server error. I guess even so the file is not used, apache still parses it.

So I tried using `AccessFilename .davaccess` to change it so some other name, which kind of works, but not in `<Location>` but only globally in `<VirtualHost>`.

So what to do? How to I disable htaccess in a `<Location>` or how do I have to change layout in order for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `<Directory>` container instead of a `<Location>` container in order to apply the `AllowOverride` directive. Whilst the `AllowOverride` directive has "directory" context (meaning that it would ordinarily be permitted in both `<Location>` and `<Directory>` containers, etc.), there is a [specific restriction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whatwhere) that states:

> The `AllowOverride` directive works only in `<Directory>` sections.

This would seem to be reasonable since `.htaccess` files apply to physical directories, not strictly URLs (although URLs often map to physical directories). (The `<Directory>` container is also processed much earlier in the request. `<Location>` containers are processed late.)

Incidentally, you'd also need to set `AllowOverrideList None` on Apache 2.4 to completely disable `.htaccess` files. And as per [the docs for `AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride):

> When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to None, **.htaccess files are completely ignored**. In this case, **the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files** in the filesystem.

I don't currently see how `.htaccess` (per-directory config files) can be conditionally enabled for an area of the filesystem (under a single virtual host). They are either enabled or not.

Reference:

- [AllowOverride Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- [What Directives are Allowed?](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whatwhere)

**UPDATE:** The solution/workaround to this is probably to have a completely separate VirtualHost (maybe the same *host*, but different *port*?) just for WebDAV that points to the same area of the filesystem, in which `.htaccess` are completely disabled. However, dot-files (primarily `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`) are also protected by default, so you would need to override this if required to allow read access.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I still don't know what to do to get webdav working in a way that it can be used to upload webs containing .htaccess files.

Comment: The solution might be to create an entirely separate server/VirtualHost just for WebDAV that points to the same area on the filesystem. I've updated my answer.